# Name of a specific visual effect

Tags: vocabulary

it's a visual effect that originates from a pack of cigarettes, which shows the pack of cigarettes on the packaging, and it goes on and on forever. basically "recursive"

Answer (score 6):

This is called the Droste effect ([Droste effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect)).

> The Droste effect (Dutch pronunciation: [ˈdrɔstə]), known in art as an example of mise en abyme, is the effect of a picture recursively appearing within itself, in a place where a similar picture would realistically be expected to appear, creating a loop which theoretically could go on forever, but realistically only goes on as far as the image's quality allows.

[image]

(*From Wikipedia*)

Comment: thanks! this was just what i was looking for. no wonder i was thinking about Ed Droste the entire time

Answer (score 4):

'**Mise en abyme**'. According to lexico.com:

> (A term denoting) self-reflection within the structure of a literary work; a work employing self-reflection.

It's also known as '**Droste effect**', a "recursive visual effect".
The Dutch Droste company used to have labels on their products that showed a woman carrying a tray on which the same product was placed, with the same woman carrying a tray with.. you get the picture:

[image]